# Utilizar el onclick en lista de opciones

Tags: html, html5, html-select

Tengo la siguiente lista desplegable código html, con la cual requiero enlazar unos reportes ya diseñados

```
<label class="w3-text-teal"><b>Tipo de Reportes&vert;</b>
         <select name="Lista" class="w3-border">
           <option value="saab">--Seleccionar--</option>
           <option value="Ante" href="Reportes/ReportTecnico">Relacion de pqr Asociados a Tecnicos</option>
           <option value="Ante" href="Reportes/pdf_generar.php">Informe General Estados pqr</option>
         </select>
 </label>    

 <br>
 <br>

<button name="Generar" type="sumbit" onclick="">Generar Reporte</button>
```

quisiera que me dieran una idea de como hacerlo empleando el evento onclick en el button

Comment: ¿Usas jquery? Parece que no pero para ayudarte en la solución podría variar el código :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En primer lugar comentarte que debes de mirar siempre los atributos que tienen los objetos de HTML que usas. En este caso options no soporta "href" como atributo. Esto te ayuda a hacer tu página mas correcta y estandar.

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/option

Entonces lo primero que habría que cambiar es el código HTML del select:

```
 <select  id="reportList" name="Lista" class="w3-border">
           <option value="saab">--Seleccionar--</option>
           <option value="ReportTecnico.php">Relacion de pqr Asociados a Tecnicos</option>
           <option value="pdf_generar.php">Informe General Estados pqr</option>
         </select>
```

Ahora tenemos en el **value** del **option** la **url del report**.

He quitado **"/Reportes"** porque parece que siempre es la misma y podría ser una variable dentro del propio javascript.

```
var reportUrl="/Reportes/";
```

La función javascript que habría que llamar desde el onclick del button (he quitado el tipo submit porque no veo formulario) sería de este tipo:

```
function generaReporte()
{

var reportList = document.getElementById("reportList");
if(reportList.selectedIndex!=0)
{
    var informe = reportList.options[reportList.selectedIndex].value;
  alert('Informe ' + informe);
}

}
```

Lógicamente en vez de hacer alert puedes hacer un **window.open**, **location.href**.. lo que necesites.

Te dejo un ejemplo que funciona tanto con jquery como sin el:

https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/32355/